# Express : using await before bcrypt.compare gives error

Tags: node.js, express, bcrypt

I am trying to use bcrypt to compare user's password with stored password.
But Express is giving error is I use await before bcrypt.compare

Here is the code :

```
app.post ('/users/login', (req, res) => {
    const user = users.find(user=> user.name === req.body.user)
    if (user == null) {
        return res.status(400).send('Can Not find user');
    } else {
        try{
            if ( await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password)) {
                res.send("Success");
            } else {
                res.send("Incorrect PAssword");
            }
        } catch {
            return res.status(500).send('Some Error has occurred');
        }
    }
});
```

I am getting this error :

```
C:\Data\Ashish\projects\jwtAuthentication\app.js:32
            if ( await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password)) {
                       ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Please help to find the mistake..

Regards,
Ashish

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot to add async to the callback function.

`app.post ('/users/login', (req, res) => {`

Should be:

`app.post ('/users/login', async (req, res) => {`

Await will work only with async functions.

It is different from the chrome console. In the console you can directly use await keyword, but in case of node.js, you need to specify async nature of the parent function in which you want to use await.

For further reference, you can refer to [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).